# Change python subclass at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change a (sub)class at runtime.

I could do

```
class X:
  def __init__(self,arg):
    pass

class A(X):
  def __init__(self,arg1,arg2):
    super().__init__(arg1)
    self.arg1 = arg1

  def transform():
    return B(self.arg1,'foo')

class B(X):
  def __init__(self,arg1,arg2):
    super().__init__(arg1)
```

and create a new X instance from the same arg1.

However is there a way to avoid having to save `arg1` in A and create a new X? More generally is there a way to transfer the super class *object* to construct B from the *same* object?

Edit:

More concretely: can I create a new class instance b of type B with super class type X from a method call on an existing class instance a of type A with super() object x of type X by directly transferring x to b, resulting in b having super() object x?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? This seems suggestive of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Brian I hope that's clearer.

Comment: You're edit still doesn't describe your motivation for trying to do this. It's worth noting that when you instantiate e.g. `A`, you don't create separate `X` and `A` objects (as is done in languages such as C++). There are no "super" and "sub" objects, just one object that happily behaves as both. There isn't any native way for Python to determine what attributes "belong" to `X` in the resulting object, and which attributes only "belong" to `A`. Also, you seem to missing a `self` parameter in `A.__init__`. I assume this is also true for the other classes.

Comment: I see it sounds like it may be difficult in python. My motivation is that I'm implementing raft consensus and would like to have a way for nodes to change their type at runtime while inheriting from the same base. e.g. Follower,Candidate,Leader inherit from Base and Follower can upgrade itself to Candidate ect. I know I could composition instead but then I would have a lot of pass through methods, extra pointer dereferencing ect. With my idea I could create Candidate from a Follower without losing the existing Base, but I think my conception of the python object model lacks

Comment: Consider [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), in particular the [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and/or [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. Python makes these easy to implement with little to no boilerplate.